# Is there a way to automatically generate a label and caption for a series of figures?

Tags: graphics, captions, labels, foreach, loops

I have a list of figures which I insert into my document using a "foreach" loop. Is there a way to also generate labels for each of these figures from within the foreach loop? I have the following code but running it produces captions, but no labels!

My example is as follows:

```
       \foreach \x in \imageNames
{
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{figures/TGA-DTG/\x.png}
        \caption{\x}
        \foreach \y in {1,2, 3,...,64}
        {\label{fig:DTG\y}}
    \end{figure}
}
```

where the preamble has:

```
    \newcommand*{\imageNames}
{AFCO 01-JAN-19,AFCO 02-NOV-18,AFCO 03-APR-19,AFCO 03-JAN-19,%
AFCO 03-OCT-18,AFCO 05-DEC-18,AFCO 05-JUL-18,AFCO 05-MAR-19,% 
AFCO 05-NOV-18,AFCO 06-FEB-19,AFCO 09-JAN-19,AFCO 12-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 13-DEC-18,AFCO 14-MAR-19,AFCO 14-OCT-18,AFCO 17-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 24-NOV-18,AFCO 27-DEC-18,AFCO 27-NOV-18,AFCO 28-FEB-19,% 
AFCO 30-DEC-18,AFCO 30-JAN-19,AUS 100,BLUESCOPE,BUSTY BLEND,BUSTY FINES,%
BUSTY IN BASE,COKE BREEZE BLEND,COLOMBIAN,FYF,IJmuiden 50CRI,MORFA 02-FEB-21,%
MORFA 14-JAN-21,MORFA 16-JAN-21,MORFA 18-JAN-21,MORFA 21-JAN-21,MORFA 29-JAN-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 02-FEB-21,MORFA FLOAT 23-02-21,MORFA FLOAT 3-FEB-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 27-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 28-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 30-JAN-21,% 
MORFA GROUND 1,MORFA GROUND 2,MORFA GROUND 3,MORFA GROUND 4,% 
MORFA GROUND 5,MORFA GROUND 6,MORFA GROUND 7,MORFA SINK 23-FEB-21,% 
MORFA SINK 24-FEB-21,MORFA SINK 27-JAN-21,MORFA SINK 28-JAN-21,%
MORFA SINK 30-JAN-21,MORFA WK 1,MORFA WK 39,MORFA WK 4,MORFA WK 8,POLISH 100,%
REF 3 BLEND 2,RISUN 10-JUL-18,RISUN ERINI P,US LV 50-50,US MV}
```

Comment: `\caption` has to be in a `figure` or use `\captionof{figure}{...}` from `capt-of` package (don't use `\\ ` before the caption)

Comment: A caption needs a figure (or table) environment, add `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` within the loop. This will probably completely mess up your layout so it would be easier not to use `\caption` at all and just print `\x` after `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE. You can use multiple variables in `\foreach`. Here's [documentation](https://tikz.dev/pgffor).

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle, I've updated the code to include your suggestions. I'm now struggling to auto-label them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first tried using a TikZ array, but without quotes it was turned into a number, and with quotes it wasn't treated as an array.

Instead I tried xstring.  I got it to work, but it isn't pretty.

Oh, and LaTeX does not like having that many floats in the queue.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

  \newcommand*{\imageNames}
{,AFCO 01-JAN-19,AFCO 02-NOV-18,AFCO 03-APR-19,AFCO 03-JAN-19,%
AFCO 03-OCT-18,AFCO 05-DEC-18,AFCO 05-JUL-18,AFCO 05-MAR-19,% 
AFCO 05-NOV-18,AFCO 06-FEB-19,AFCO 09-JAN-19,AFCO 12-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 13-DEC-18,AFCO 14-MAR-19,AFCO 14-OCT-18,AFCO 17-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 24-NOV-18,AFCO 27-DEC-18,AFCO 27-NOV-18,AFCO 28-FEB-19,% 
AFCO 30-DEC-18,AFCO 30-JAN-19,AUS 100,BLUESCOPE,BUSTY BLEND,BUSTY FINES,%
BUSTY IN BASE,COKE BREEZE BLEND,COLOMBIAN,FYF,IJmuiden 50CRI,MORFA 02-FEB-21,%
MORFA 14-JAN-21,MORFA 16-JAN-21,MORFA 18-JAN-21,MORFA 21-JAN-21,MORFA 29-JAN-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 02-FEB-21,MORFA FLOAT 23-02-21,MORFA FLOAT 3-FEB-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 27-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 28-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 30-JAN-21,% 
MORFA GROUND 1,MORFA GROUND 2,MORFA GROUND 3,MORFA GROUND 4,% 
MORFA GROUND 5,MORFA GROUND 6,MORFA GROUND 7,MORFA SINK 23-FEB-21,% 
MORFA SINK 24-FEB-21,MORFA SINK 27-JAN-21,MORFA SINK 28-JAN-21,%
MORFA SINK 30-JAN-21,MORFA WK 1,MORFA WK 39,MORFA WK 4,MORFA WK 8,POLISH 100,%
REF 3 BLEND 2,RISUN 10-JUL-18,RISUN ERINI P,US LV 50-50,US MV,}

\begin{document}

\foreach \y in {1,...,32}% too many will crash
{
    \begin{figure}[p]% only [p] can fill an entire page
    \centering
        \count1=\y\relax
        \count2=\numexpr \y+1\relax
        \StrBetween[\count1,\count2]{\imageNames}{,}{,}[\x]%
        \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{figures/TGA-DTG/\x.png}
        \caption{\x}
        \label{fig:DTG\y}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

---

Just for fun, this uses a `\csname` array.

Note that the only way to include a numeral in a macro name is by using `\csname ... \endcsname`.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

  \newcommand*{\imageNames}
{AFCO 01-JAN-19,AFCO 02-NOV-18,AFCO 03-APR-19,AFCO 03-JAN-19,%
AFCO 03-OCT-18,AFCO 05-DEC-18,AFCO 05-JUL-18,AFCO 05-MAR-19,% 
AFCO 05-NOV-18,AFCO 06-FEB-19,AFCO 09-JAN-19,AFCO 12-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 13-DEC-18,AFCO 14-MAR-19,AFCO 14-OCT-18,AFCO 17-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 24-NOV-18,AFCO 27-DEC-18,AFCO 27-NOV-18,AFCO 28-FEB-19,% 
AFCO 30-DEC-18,AFCO 30-JAN-19,AUS 100,BLUESCOPE,BUSTY BLEND,BUSTY FINES,%
BUSTY IN BASE,COKE BREEZE BLEND,COLOMBIAN,FYF,IJmuiden 50CRI,MORFA 02-FEB-21,%
MORFA 14-JAN-21,MORFA 16-JAN-21,MORFA 18-JAN-21,MORFA 21-JAN-21,MORFA 29-JAN-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 02-FEB-21,MORFA FLOAT 23-02-21,MORFA FLOAT 3-FEB-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 27-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 28-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 30-JAN-21,% 
MORFA GROUND 1,MORFA GROUND 2,MORFA GROUND 3,MORFA GROUND 4,% 
MORFA GROUND 5,MORFA GROUND 6,MORFA GROUND 7,MORFA SINK 23-FEB-21,% 
MORFA SINK 24-FEB-21,MORFA SINK 27-JAN-21,MORFA SINK 28-JAN-21,%
MORFA SINK 30-JAN-21,MORFA WK 1,MORFA WK 39,MORFA WK 4,MORFA WK 8,POLISH 100,%
REF 3 BLEND 2,RISUN 10-JUL-18,RISUN ERINI P,US LV 50-50,US MV}

\newcounter{index}
\foreach \x in \imageNames {% create \imageName1, \imageName2. ...
  \stepcounter{index}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname imageName\theindex\endcsname{\x}%
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\foreach \y in {1,...,32}% too many will crash
{
    \begin{figure}[p]% only [p] can fill an entire page
    \centering
        \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{figures/TGA-DTG/\csname imageName\y\endcsname.png}
        \caption{\csname imageName\y\endcsname}
        \label{fig:DTG\y}
    \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately, I don't think the auto-labels are working as when I try to reference a single plot, typing \ref{fig:} only brings up "DTG\y"...is this intended?

Comment: fixed by changing it to: \caption{\x \label{fig:DTG\y}}

Comment: Interesting!  It shouldn't make a difference as long as \caption and \label are in the same group (in this case, figure).

Comment: apologies, I think I spoke too soon! It unfortunately didn't change the outcome, the labelling still doesn't work!

Comment: I get \ref{fig:DTG1} to return the caption number (1).  What were you expecting?

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it works! I was confused because the autoprompt didn't come up on overleaf, but I guess it worked! apologies for the confusion...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\foreach` from the PGF/TikZ codebase which means that you can use the `count` optional extra to keep track of how many images have been processed.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654216/86}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\imageNames}
{AFCO 01-JAN-19,AFCO 02-NOV-18,AFCO 03-APR-19,AFCO 03-JAN-19,%
AFCO 03-OCT-18,AFCO 05-DEC-18,AFCO 05-JUL-18,AFCO 05-MAR-19,% 
AFCO 05-NOV-18,AFCO 06-FEB-19,AFCO 09-JAN-19,AFCO 12-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 13-DEC-18,AFCO 14-MAR-19,AFCO 14-OCT-18,AFCO 17-DEC-18,% 
AFCO 24-NOV-18,AFCO 27-DEC-18,AFCO 27-NOV-18,AFCO 28-FEB-19,% 
AFCO 30-DEC-18,AFCO 30-JAN-19,AUS 100,BLUESCOPE,BUSTY BLEND,BUSTY FINES,%
BUSTY IN BASE,COKE BREEZE BLEND,COLOMBIAN,FYF,IJmuiden 50CRI,MORFA 02-FEB-21,%
MORFA 14-JAN-21,MORFA 16-JAN-21,MORFA 18-JAN-21,MORFA 21-JAN-21,MORFA 29-JAN-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 02-FEB-21,MORFA FLOAT 23-02-21,MORFA FLOAT 3-FEB-21,% 
MORFA FLOAT 27-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 28-JAN-21,MORFA FLOAT 30-JAN-21,% 
MORFA GROUND 1,MORFA GROUND 2,MORFA GROUND 3,MORFA GROUND 4,% 
MORFA GROUND 5,MORFA GROUND 6,MORFA GROUND 7,MORFA SINK 23-FEB-21,% 
MORFA SINK 24-FEB-21,MORFA SINK 27-JAN-21,MORFA SINK 28-JAN-21,%
MORFA SINK 30-JAN-21,MORFA WK 1,MORFA WK 39,MORFA WK 4,MORFA WK 8,POLISH 100,%
REF 3 BLEND 2,RISUN 10-JUL-18,RISUN ERINI P,US LV 50-50,US MV}

\begin{document}

\foreach[count=\y] \x in \imageNames
{
  \begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  Float: \x, Figure: \y
%  \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{figures/TGA-DTG/\x.png}
  \caption{\x}
  \label{fig:DTG\y}
  \end{figure}

  \lipsum[1]
}


\end{document}
```

I've added in a dummy paragraph (from the `lipsum` package) between each figure to avoid the "Too many floats" issue.  I figure that that is a side issue to what you are trying to solve here. Also, as I don't have the actual images then I commented out the `\includegraphics`.