# Macro to define macros within .aux file is not working

Tags: expl3, package-writing, auxiliary-files, write, primitives

Here are some macros that I am trying to define (based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654755)):

- `\odef{foo}{bar}` will define an "object" with name `foo` and value `bar`.
- `\objRef{foo}` will insert the value of the `foo` "object."

These macros should allow me to reference variables defined *anywhere* in my document. For example, doing this:

```tex
Lorem ipsum dolor \objRef{sentence-Ends/lipsum}.

% INSERT OTHER PARTS OF MY DOCUMENT HERE (CHAPTERS, SECTIONS, FIGURES, TABLES, ETC.)

Defining variables now... \odef{sentence-Ends/lipsum}{sit amet} Done!
```

should produce

> Lorem ipsum dolor ???.
>
> Definining variables now... Done!

after the first run of LaTeX and

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
>
> Definining variables now... Done!

after the second run.

I wrote this code in objectref.sty, but it is not working as expected—I always get `???` on the page and the undefined warning in my log file.

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{objectref}[Create and reference custom variables in LaTeX documents]

\def\odef#1#2{\immediate\write\@auxout{\expandafter\def \csname obj:#1\endcsname {#2}}}
\def\objRef#1{\ifcsname obj:#1\endcsname \csname obj:#1\endcsname \else ??? \PackageWarning{objectref}{Object #1 undefined on input line \the\inputlineno.}\fi}
```

Among other things, the .aux file generated when I compile my document contains:

```tex
\def \obj:sentence-Ends/lipsum {sit amet}
```

which *should* mean that everything will work properly (alas, it does not).

**What is the problem with my code, and how do I fix it?**

Comment: `\def\obj:sentence-Ends/lipsum {sit amet}` creates a macro `\obj` with a delimiter `sentence-Ends/lipsum`.  You'll either need to either write the macro name wrapped in `\csname`/`\endcsname` to the `.aux` file or only use letters + `@` in the macro name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you should use `\gdef` and not `\def`, because the `.aux` file is read inside a group.

Second problem: with your code you get

```
\def \obj:sentence-Ends/lipsum {...}
```

in the `.aux` file, but this defines `\obj`.

Third problem: if you do

```
\odef{test}{\'amet}
```

the `.aux` file will contain garbage (try it).

Fourth problem: you get spurious spaces in the output, if you plan to say `\odef` in the middle of a paragraph.

##### Proposed solution.

Don't write `\def` nor `\gdef` in the `.aux` file and make the replacement text not to expand. Also use `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\odef}[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\objectref@def{#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand{\objectref@def}[2]{\global\@namedef{obj:#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\objRef}[1]{%
  \ifcsname obj:#1\endcsname
    \csname obj:#1\endcsname
  \else
    ???%
    \PackageWarning{objectref}{Object #1 undefined on input line \the\inputlineno.}%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor \objRef{sentence-Ends/lipsum}

Defining variables now... \odef{sentence-Ends/lipsum}{sit \'amet} Done!

Defining variables now... Done!% added line to check spaces

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file will be

```
\relax 
\objectref@def{sentence-Ends/lipsum}{sit \'amet}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

The output is

[image]

If I comment out `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`, I get

[image]

and the wrong spacing is clear.

A different version where the second argument to `\odef` is safely expanded in the `.aux` file; safely means that accents and other dangerous command need not be protected.

This is achieved with the more powerful functions of `expl3`, in particular `\text_expand:n` that precisely does the job we need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\odef}{mm}
 {
  \use:c { @bsphack }
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout } { \token_to_str:N \objectrefdef { #1 } { \text_expand:n { #2 } } }
  \use:c { @esphack }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\objectrefdef}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_benz_objectref_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_benz_objectref_prop

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\objRef}{m}
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_benz_objectref_prop { #1 }
   {
    \prop_item:Nn \g_benz_objectref_prop { #1 }
   }
   {
    ???
    \PackageWarning{objectref}{Object~#1~undefined}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{Counter}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor \objRef{sentence-Ends/lipsum}

Defining variables now... \odef{sentence-Ends/lipsum}{sit \'amet} Done!

Defining variables now... Done!% added line to check spaces

\stepcounter{Counter}

\odef{Name with space}{The counter value hêr\'e is \theCounter}

\stepcounter{Counter} % now 2

\objRef{Name with space}

\end{document}
```

Note that spaces in the first argument of `\odef` are honored and that the value of `Counter` current at `\odef` time is used.

[image]

Comment: Works very well! I like that you configured the macro to use the unexpanded version of the text in the .aux file, but one of my use cases is storing the value of a counter at the point of `\odef`. `\odef{myObj}{\theCounter}` just prints out the value of the counter *at the point of use* (i.e., where I write `\objectRef`)—how can I print the value of the counter *at the point of definition*? Something like `\odef{myObj}{\expand\theCounter}` (this doesn't actually work)?

Comment: Also, is there a way to allow spaces within the object name? For example, `\odef{My Object}{Hello, world!}`.

Comment: @BenZ. Spaces should work out of the box. For the other problem, it mostly depend on what you expect to have in the second argument to `\odef`. Is it just either text or a *single* macro such as `\theCounter`? However, if you only plan to use counter representations there, the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism can be used without needing any other infrastructure.

Comment: Is there a command that I can put *in* the second argument to `\odef` that will allow me to expand a counter then and there, if I use one in the argument? So I would like to be able to do something like `\odef{myObj}{The counter value here is \theCounter}`, but using the value of the `Counter` counter *at the point of writing* `\odef`.

Comment: @BenZ. I added a version that does the more complex job you need.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give minimal example, so my answer is only theoretical and not checked. Define `\sdef` macro with usage:

```
\sdef{text}{body}
```

which define `\csname text\endcsname` as body. And use it in `.aux` file. So:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\odef#1#2{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\sdef{obj:#1}{#2}}}
\def\objRef#1{\ifcsname obj:#1\endcsname \csname obj:#1\endcsname \else ??? \PackageWarning{objectref}{Object #1 undefined on input line \the\inputlineno.}\fi}
```