# How to put multiple figures (with partial regular name) into Latex with section ranking number and picture name

Tags: floats

[image]
I want to put multiple figures (with partial regular name) into Latex with section ranking number and picture name, could you teach me how to do that?

The picture's format is .jpg, please find the detailed name in the picture below, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "section ranking number and picture name"?

Comment: for example, in the Chapter 3, the picture number will be ranked like 3.1 XXX, 3.2 XXX...thanks for your question

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98748/including-many-figures-from-a-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668932/how-can-i-use-a-for-loop-to-display-50-pictures-on-a-page or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654216/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-a-label-and-caption-for-a-series-of-fig for example.

Comment: Dear Marijn, Thanks for your valuable and useful information, I'll study the examples looking for the best solution!